# how can i get the path of a file in the project explorer of exlipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

i will build an eclipse rcp. in this context i will add some some views into this rcp. the views will be the project explorer view, editor like the same with the eclipse ide. and there will be some other views corresponding to my project.beside this i also have a databasetable, where the files are saved with their paths. so the thing is: if the user clicks to a file, then i will get the path of the file or save it into a variable so that i can compare the path of the selected file with the existing files of the databasetable... so their will not be another view, who will use this i hope i could explain my question better

My questions is.in the project explorer view of the eclipse ide.if you click on a file, then i would like to get the path of this file.does anyone know how i can get the path of a file in the project exlporer. or is this path saved anywhere, so i can get the path of the file from this place.

i will try to explain my qustion with this example:

if i click on the File: abc.java

and the path of the abc.java File in the project explorer is for example: Example/src/abc.java

My question is:

where can i find the path of the File  abc.java or is this path saved anywhere?

or better:

if  i click on the abc.java File 
how can i get the path of this abc.java, to use this path for other topics.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `ISelectionService` to get the current selection:

```java
ISelectionService service = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService();

ISelection selection = service.getSelection();

if (selection instanceof IStructuredSelection)
 {
   Object selected = ((IStructuredSelection)selection).getFirstElement();

   IFile file = (IFile)Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(selected, IFile.class);

   .... use file
 }
```

The current selection will be in whatever view or editor is currently active. You can also ask the selection service for the current selection in a particular view.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the answer is that you need to get to the selection as an IFile. Then you can just ask the IFile for its path using getFullPath(). See http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIFile.html

But you need to provide more context for this question. Do you have a popup menu action that's being passed the selection? Are you registering a selection listener from some other view? Or something else entirely? Basically, you need to tell us what context you're in and what data you have available.

Answer (score 0):

i will build an eclipse rcp.
in this context i will add some some views into this rcp. the views will be the project explorer view, editor like the same with the eclipse ide. and there will be some other views corresponding to my project.beside this i also have a databasetable, where the files are saved with their paths. so the thing is: if the user clicks to a file, then i will get the path of the file or save it into a variable so that i can compare the path of the selected file with the existing files of the databasetable...
so their will not be another view, who will use this
i hope i could explain my questio  better

thanks